# TypeError: expected string or bytes-like object

Tags: python, beautifulsoup, html-parsing

I've written a [script](http://tamil.thehindu.com/opinion/blogs/%E0%AE%8E%E0%AE%AE%E0%AF%8D%E0%AE%9C%E0%AE%BF%E0%AE%86%E0%AE%B0%E0%AF%8D-100-19-%E0%AE%B8%E0%AF%8D%E0%AE%B0%E0%AF%80%E0%AE%A4%E0%AE%B0%E0%AF%81%E0%AE%95%E0%AF%8D%E0%AE%95%E0%AF%81%E0%AE%9A%E0%AF%8D-%E0%AE%9A%E0%AF%86%E0%AE%AF%E0%AF%8D%E0%AE%A4-%E0%AE%89%E0%AE%A4%E0%AE%B5%E0%AE%BF/article8340578.ece?ref=sliderNews) to parse html and print the text content only. I wanted to ignore the tags. But my program has a problem. I am not sure what it is. Please help me.

[image]

```
import urllib.request
import re
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
url = "www.example.com"

def hi():
    dep = urllib.request.urlopen(url)
    soup = BeautifulSoup(dep, 'html.parser')
    for link in soup.find_all('p', string=True):
        result = re.sub(b'<.*?>', "", link)
        print (result)
hi()
```

The website [link](http://tamil.thehindu.com/opinion/blogs/%E0%AE%8E%E0%AE%AE%E0%AF%8D%E0%AE%9C%E0%AE%BF%E0%AE%86%E0%AE%B0%E0%AF%8D-100-19-%E0%AE%B8%E0%AF%8D%E0%AE%B0%E0%AF%80%E0%AE%A4%E0%AE%B0%E0%AF%81%E0%AE%95%E0%AF%8D%E0%AE%95%E0%AF%81%E0%AE%9A%E0%AF%8D-%E0%AE%9A%E0%AF%86%E0%AE%AF%E0%AF%8D%E0%AE%A4-%E0%AE%89%E0%AE%A4%E0%AE%B5%E0%AE%BF/article8340578.ece?ref=sliderNews).

Comment: add the code here.

Comment: and make sure to include the full traceback as text and what you have tried to solve the issue.

Comment: @Vasanth post the code not the url you tried to scrape..

Comment: I have added my code here. thanks in advance.

Comment: Convert your screenshot to valid code and valid traceback. You posted really messy thing before editing.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I believe, that you have `NavigableString` in `link` variable.

Force cast it to string like:

```
for link in soup.find_all('p', string=True):
    result = re.sub(b'<.*?>', "", str(link))
    print (result)
```

Comment: But now, It shows me a TypeError: cannot use a bytes pattern on a string-like object.

Comment: change `b'<.*?>'` to `r'<.*?>'`.

Comment: Hurrayyyy... Thank you so much. Can you explain that line? because I copied that line from another code. I don't know what is the logic behind :)

Comment: @VasanthPrabakar, r is for regexp, b is for byte. Their behaviour also varies from version to version of python.

Comment: `r` is for raw, not regexp.  It helps with regular expression because they use `\\` differently from how strings normally treat it, but it was not created for regular expressions; it just means raw.